# C# "discovery" return type feature

Tags: c#, .net, var

in c#, when returning a value, it is not nescessary to specify the variable type.
For instance:

```
foreach(var variable in variables) {
}
```

I am building a corporate software that today is a small solution but it is going to be big.
This language feature could decrease performance as we use it over and over on our application?

I have not found how this feature is called and I would like to know more about it, how it is called?

Comment: A google for "c# var" gets this back http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx immediately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`var` is used for `implicitly typing` variables.

It happens at compile time. There is no performance issue.

- See [this MSDN article about `var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)
- Or [this one on implicitly typed variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Examples:

```
var i = 12; // This will be compiled as an integer
var s = "Implicitly typed!"; // This will be compiled as a string
var l = new List<string>(); // This will be compiled as a List of strings
```

Comment: Hmm, be careful.  There are a lot of collection types in .NET, the old ones, where the variable in the foreach loop is inferred to be of type *object*.  Getting it unboxed early can certainly make a difference.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you give an example? Are you talking about the pre-generics collections?

Comment: @HansPassant I have just confirmed that is what you meant. Is there a reason you bought that up given that I used a generic list? Or was that meant for the OP?

Answer (score 5):

`Var` is an `implicit type`. It aliases any type in the C# programming language. The aliased type is determined by the C# compiler. This has no performance penalty. The `var` keyword has equivalent performance. It does not affect *runtime* behavior.

```
var i = 5; // i is compiled as an int
var i = "5" ; // i is compiled as a string 
var i = new[] { 0, 1, 2 }; // i is compiled as an int[] 
var i = new[] { "0", "1", "2" }; // i is compiled as an string[] 
var i = new { Name = "Soner", Age = 24 }; // i is compiled as an anonymous type 
var i = new List<int>(); // i is compiled as List<int>
```

There are also some limitations for `var` keyword. You can't assign a `var` to `null`.  You also can't use `var` as a *parameter type* or a *return value* of a method either.

Check out from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the `var` is an `implicit type`, the compiler works out at `compile-time` what type `var` should be. No performance issues. You can write some test code, compile, and use `ildasm.exe` to check generated `CIL`

[MSDN - View Assembly Contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605.aspx)

---

**[Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/var)**

> Note: The int declaration is the same as the var declaration in the IL. So the execution engine doesn't know that you used var.
>
> And: They are compiled to the same IL. *The var keyword is equally fast as explicit types like int or string.*
>
> **Intermediate Language Method using var [C#]**

```
> public int ReturnValue() {
>     var a = 5;
>     int b = 5;
> 
>     return a + b; }
```

> IL of the method

```
.method public hidebysig instance int32  ReturnValue() cil managed
{
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 result,
       [1] int32 CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  br.s       IL_0007
  IL_0007:  ldloc.1
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method VarKW::ReturnValue
```